# how to make schema diagram

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-schema

i have a problem. i want to make a schema. and the diagram for the tables and showing relationship between them. 
i downloaded management studio 2008 and sql sever 2008.
 i was going through the Help and came across this :
"
To create a schema by using SQL Server Management Studio
In SQL Server Management Studio, open Object Explorer and expand the Databases folder.
Expand the database in which to create the new database schema.
**Right-click the Security folder, point to New, and then click Schema.**
On the General page, enter a name for the new schema in the Schema name box.
In the Schema owner box, enter the name of a database user or role to own the schema.
Click OK.

"

however there is no Schema option , when i right click :s
what to do ?
please help?

Answer (score 1):

One option as to why you are not getting the option to create a Schema is that you went to the Security folder at the server level, make sure that you first expand a database and go to the security folder inside it, there it should appear the option to create a new schema.

Anyway, I believe that you may be somehow confused, since you are talking about a diagram with table relationships. If that is what you really want, you need to create a database diagram. For this, you should expand the database where you want to create that diagram, right click the "Database Diagrams" folder, and choose the "New Database Diagram" option.